# Is there a way to programmatically maximize/minimize WinRT application?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, maximize-window

For win forms I can set the windowState to maximize my current window. What is the equivalent to maximize or minimize the winRT application window?

WinForm:
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

Comment: [TryEnterFullScreenMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode.aspx) might partially solve your problem, but it's not the same as "maximized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by maximize. If you mean like how WPF apps can do it, the simple answer is no. That is not possible. Using TryEnterFullScreenMode will make your application maximized-like, but it's not likely to be what you want. There's no good Minimize workaround either. That being said, you can Resize your app to be bigger and smaller, but never like Min/Max.